# How to conditionally update DataFrame column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

With this DataFrame, how can I conditionally set `rating` to 0 when `line_race` is equal to zero?

```
    line_track  line_race  rating foreign
 25        MTH         10     84    False
 26        MTH          6     88    False
 27        TAM          5     87    False
 28         GP          2     86    False
 29         GP          7     59    False
 30        LCH          0    103     True
 31        LEO          0    125     True
 32        YOR          0    126     True
 33        ASC          0    124     True
```

In other words, what is the proper way on a DataFrame to say if ColumnA = x then ColumnB = y else ColumnB = ColumnB

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['line_race'] == 0, 'rating'] = 0
```

Answer (score 21):

Use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to say *if ColumnA = x then ColumnB = y else ColumnB = ColumnB*:

```
df['rating'] = np.where(df['line_race']==0, 0, df['rating'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have always used method given in Selected answer, today I faced a need where I need to Update column A, conditionally with derived values.
the accepted answer shows "how to update column line_race to 0.
Below is an example where you have to derive value to be updated with:

```
df.loc[df['line_race'].isna(), 'rating'] = ( (df['line_race'] - df['line_race2'])/df['line_race2'] )
```

Using this you can UPDATE dynamic values ONLY on Rows Matching a Condition.