# How to update value in column cells based on other column cells in the same csv file bys using python?

Tags: python, csv

Let's suppose that I have a big data in a csv file:

```
frame.number    frame.len   frame.cap_len   frame.Type  
  1               100           100           ICMP  
  2                64            64           UDP   
  3               100           100           ICMP  
  4                87            64           ICMP
```

I want to change the type of the frame based on its length. 
The first problem is that I don't know how to extract the rank of the column, then change the frame typelike this:

```
if frame.len==100 then it puts frame.type=ICMP_tt else if frame.len==87 then it puts frame.type=ICMP_nn
```

I would like that it looks like this:

```
frame.number    frame.len   frame.cap_len   frame.Type  
  1               100           100           ICMP_tt   
  2                64            64           UDP   
  3               100           100           ICMP_tt   
  4                87            64           ICMP_nn
```

I try by using this code but it doesn't  make any modification.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('Test.csv')
if df['frame.len'] == 100:
    df['frame.type'].replace("ICMP_tt")
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question: [How to conditionally update DataFrame column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196203/how-to-conditionally-update-dataframe-column-in-pandas)

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('Test.csv')
df.loc[df['frame.len'] == 100, 'frame.Type'] = "ICMP_tt"
df.loc[df['frame.len'] == 87, 'frame.Type'] = "ICMP_nn"
df
```

Result: 
    [image]

Should do the trick. The first item given to `df.loc[]` is an array full of True/False values telling it which rows to update (will also accept single number as the row index if I recall correctly), and the second item specifies which column to update.

Comment: But I don't have any modification, that it is my problem.

Comment: Do you mind sending me a csv or a pickle? Pickle would be better. By send I mean something like sharing it on google drive...

Comment: it is a big file, I try to test  with those set of lines. Do you think that I need to save results in a new files.

Comment: Yes, it will not directly affect the csv file; it will only alter the data in the DataFrame object. For it to actually affect your csv you will have to write it out using something like `df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)`.