# How to update value of column B if column A contains some specific string or set of words out of sentence in column A

Tags: python, substring, contains, sentence

If column A has sentence: hb_mumbai refinery data. So i need to check if column A contains hb_mumbai then update the value of column B to : hb_mumbai

I have tried to implement it using contains function but it did not produced desired output.

```
if df['A'].str.contains('hb_mumbai'): 
    df['B']=='hb_mumbai'
```

Actual result: Value of column B is not getting updated
Desired result: Value of column B should get updated.

Comment: u can use `numpy.where` for this which is more efficient , `df.A = np.where(df.B.str.contains('hb_mumbai'),'hb_mumbai', df.A)`. Do `import numpy as np` also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally update DataFrame column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196203/how-to-conditionally-update-dataframe-column-in-pandas)

Comment: while using where() can we give more than one condition in contains() function?

Answer (score 2):

'=='is equality operator, not assigning values, use '=' instead

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is a dictionary then you could do:

```
if 'hb_mumbai' in df['A']:
    df['B']='hb_mumbai'
```

As mentioned `==` is used for checking equality; `=` would assign a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":['hb_mumbai in here','asd','qwe'],
                   "B":['123','456','789'] })

print(df)


df['B'] = ['hb_mumbai' if 'hb_mumbai' in a else b for a,b in zip(df['A'],df['A'])]

print(df)
```