# compare two strings with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I try to compare two columns (string type) in dataframe
:

```
if((MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT']== "4") and (MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT_CODE'] == ' ')):
    MODEL_STANDARD_df['ft2'] = "DIESEL"
```

but i get this error :

```
 Error in Python process: At line 18: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>:
 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
 a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). More info about this error
```

Any idea please to resolve this problem?

Thansk

Comment: Did you try searching with the error message - `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
 a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`? Were any of those results helpful? If any of those results answered your question, let us know which one and we will mark yours as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally update DataFrame column in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196203/how-to-conditionally-update-dataframe-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the values from the series to create a boolean mask indicating where the conditions are simultaneously true in both columns using
numpy's `logical_and` method:

```
import numpy as np

MODEL_STANDARD_df.loc[np.logical_and(MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT'].values=="4",MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT_CODE'].values==' '), 'ft2'] = "DIESEL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value of `MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT']== "4"` and `MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT_CODE'] == ' '` is boolean series, you cann't use `and` on `Series`. you could use boolean indexing like:

```py
MODEL_STANDARD_df['ft2'] = ""
MODEL_STANDARD_df.loc[ (MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT']== "4") & (MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT_CODE'] == ' '), 'ft2'] = "DIESEL"
```

Take the following dataframe as an example

```
FT    FT_CODE
4       3
4      ' '
4       2
4      ' '
5      ' '
```

`(MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT']== "4")` returns

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: FT, dtype: bool
```

`MODEL_STANDARD_df['FT_CODE'] == ' '` returns

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: FT_CODE, dtype: bool
```

`&` has the same logic with `and`, which means if all True then True, so `&` of two boolean series is

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

[Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) means selecting only the True rows.

Comment: it does not create a column ft2

Comment: @butter How about adding `MODEL_STANDARD_df['ft2'] = ""` before the boolean indexing?

Comment: I dont uderstand with all the 3 solution i got an empty column as result :/

Comment: @butter What's the column type of `FT`? print it with `print(df.dtypes)` and if it is `int`. Consider change the column type to str with `df['FT'].astype(str)` or changing  `== "4"` to `== 4`.

Comment: Ok, i change the type to Decimals.. and still not working

Comment: @butter Edited my code a little bit and add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a apply function along your dataframe. See example below:

```
MODEL_STANDARD_df = pd.DataFrame({'FT': ["4", "1", "3"], "FT_CODE": [' ', '1', '4']})
MODEL_STANDARD_df['ft2'] = MODEL_STANDARD_df.apply(lambda x: "DIESEL" if x.FT == "4" and x.FT_CODE == " " else None, axis=1)
```

`

Comment: same problem : empty ft2

Comment: Let me see if I understood you. You want to create a third column in your datafram which if the FT column is 4 and FT_CODE is empty, the third column would be "DIESEL", right? And the others rows, what is the value when the condition is not reached?

Comment: Still blocked since 24H :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undestand you. Who or what is still blocked? In pandas, you can't evaluate a dataframe column (ie, a pd.Series) to a single value. You can use a .loc, that check where in the dataframe your condition is reached, or use apply, that executes a function for each row, or column, in your dataframe. If your question is about this, please, say me.